# Getting a dropdown to interact with a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which looks something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  PageSize="10"
        DataKeyNames="id" 
        OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
        OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
        OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
        OnPageIndexChanged="GridView1_PageIndexChanged"
        AllowPaging="True">
```

Works fine.  I want to add a dropdown box above the gridview which will act as a filter for the database results:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Show all</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">In queue</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Being worked on</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Complete</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Declined</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

How do I get the dropdown to interact with the gridview to update the results accordingly?  Keeping in mind that the gridview has Paging enabled, so the dropdown option should be remembered when pages are clicked on and the database results should also be remembered based on the page number and the dropdown selection.

**UPDATE:**

I populate the gridview as follows where BindData goes into Page_Load:

```
private void BindData()
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"sql query here", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;

    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Page_Load looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you populate gridview with data?

Comment: @Andrei, I've added the update to the question to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `BindData()` method you need to pass the filter value from `DropDownList1` if one has been selected and amend the SQL accordingly. You may also need to pass the requested page number in your SQL statement so the results can be filtered in your `SELECT` (depending on how you are doing paging as you haven't stated).

Then in your `AutoPostBack` method for `DropDownList1` call `BindData()`.

This way each time the drop down list value is changed it will call your `BindData()` method and pas any relevant filters and page number to get the relevant results.

Answer (score 0):

You can write following code in DropDownList1's indexchnage event

```
DataView dataView = dt.DefaultView;
dataView.RowFilter = "NewsDate2 = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'";

GridView1.DataSource = dataView;
GridView1.DataBind();
```